# Save/Open Common Dialog boxes in win32 without MFC

Tags: c++, file, winapi, dialog

How do you create the deafault Save/Open dialog boxes using pure unmanaged Win32 API ?
Following the guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), the following code is executed when `WM_CREATE` message is handled in the message loop of the main window: 
Ive `included <Commdlg.h>` also.

```
            OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
        char Buffer[300];
        fill(Buffer, Buffer + 300, '\0');
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAMEA);
        ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
        ofn.lpstrFile = Buffer;
        ofn.nMaxFile = 300;
        ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER;
        ofn.lpstrFilter = NULL;
        ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
        ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
        ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
        ofn.lpstrTitle = NULL;
        out << GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn) << endl;
        out << Buffer << (int)CommDlgExtendedError();
```

However, this code gives **NO** output whatsoever. Help?!

Comment: why would you stream the return value to out!!!

Comment: Umm because the project was setup as a Win 32 type, with no console, and I didnt want to create a label to display it. 

That is why you stream the return value.

Comment: No, but I can see the main program

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the following code is executed when WM_CREATE message is handled

Look in the Output window and observe the first-chance exception notification for 0xc0000005, an AccessViolation exception.  There's a backstop in the Wow64 emulator that swallows exceptions while WM_CREATE is being dispatched.

The exception is caused by not fully initializing the OPENFILENAMEA structure.  Quick fix:

```
 OPENFILENAMEA ofn = {0};
```

And favor displaying the dialog before calling ShowWindow() instead of the WM_CREATE message handler.

Answer (score 2):

The overall idea is right, but if you are passing the handle of the window you are creating as the owner, then it is not going to be initialized yet.

For diagnostics, consider creating variables to store the API function return values and examining them in the debugger.

It is also more convenient and less error-prone to initialize the structure to zero, instead of explictely zeroing out unneeded members, like this:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetOpenFileName` blocks (for a while), and then returns either `TRUE` if the dialog was closed by 'OK', or `FALSE` if it was cancelled.

The actual result (the directory/file path) can be read from the `OPENFILENAME` structure.

Comment: But no Dialog opens up, so why does it return ?

Answer (score 0):

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes#opening-a-file we get a utf-16 version of this, with some small changes of mine:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };       // common dialog box structure
WCHAR szFile[260];       // buffer for file name 
HWND hwnd;              // owner window
HANDLE hf;              // file handle

// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
// Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
// use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

// Display the Open dialog box. 

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) 
    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, 
                    GENERIC_READ,
                    0,
                    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    (HANDLE) NULL);
```

Comment: `nMaxFile` is the "size, in characters, of the buffer pointed to by lpstrFile", yet you're setting it as the byte size of the buffer. This will cause a buffer overflow.