# Open File Dialog Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, api

How do you show the Open File Dialog on Windows using just straight C++ and the Windows API?
I'm trying to load an image to display on the screen.

Comment: Call [`GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save/Open Common Dialog boxes in win32 without MFC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729693/save-open-common-dialog-boxes-in-win32-without-mfc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want the common file dialog API, specifically GetOpenFileName - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx